# Leaving jqGrid Edit Form Open when Clicking Outside of it

Tags: jqgrid

My web page has several module accessed by tabs. Each module is in a separate div container. The problem is I open the add or edit form of a jqGrid in one module and begin to complete it. Then I decide that I need so info from another module. When I click the second module the jqGrid dialog(add, edit form) closes. I have tried the modal and jqModal set to true but this renders all other modules inaccessible as long as the jqGrid form is open.

Answer (score 0):

It I correctly understand your problem you can solve it by usage the option `overlay: 0`. Form editing will don't create the overlay during opening of editing form and you will able to work with another part of your page without closing the edit form.

Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Overlay0.htm). You can sort columns for example.

Comment: Thanks Oleg. That worked to keep the form from closing when clicking on another area of the page. However, the form has lost its styling and appears larger than when the overlay: 0 is removed. Any ideas on how to keep styling in tact?

Comment: @SteveDyke: You are welcome! Look at [my demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Overlay0.htm). I see no problem with "larger form".

Comment: I see that. But every thing about my form is enlarged. It has not been styled by the container styling like it was before setting the overlay.

Comment: @SteveDyke: I don't think that it's depend on `overlay: 0`. I suppose that you use *another version* of jqGrid. For example version 4.7 have the bug with closing and opening the edit form. The bud is not exist in jqGrid 4.6 and I fixed the bug in [free jqGrid 4.8](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). **Which version of jqGrid you use?**

Comment: @SteveDyke: Sorry, but [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Overlay0.htm) which I created for my answer of your question uses already jqGrid 4.6 and you can see that it has no problem. So the problem with "larger form" in your application should have another reason. Can you provide the demo which reproduces the problem?